# Missing Operator in batch game

Tags: batch-file

This is my script. Whenever the player goes to this part of the script it says missing operator. But it only says it the first time. Help.

```
:M221
(
set /p Gold=<"%CD%\Data Files\gold.dat"
)
set /a gold=%gold%+60
echo You have earned 60 gold today. Time to go home and go to bed.
pause
cls
goto home3

:M321
(
set /p Gold=<"%CD%\Data Files\gold.dat"
)
set /a gold=%gold%+80
echo You have earned 80 gold today. Time to go home and go to bed.
pause
cls
goto home3

:M421
(
set /p Gold=<"%CD%\Data Files\gold.dat"
)
set /a gold=%gold%+150
echo You have made a spectacular sword and earned 150 gold today. Time to go home and go to bed.
pause
cls
goto home3
```

Comment: Really, close-voters? Off-topic? In what way exactly is batch file code not programming-related?

Comment: Sadly, there seems to be a band of close-voters mechanically applying their anaonymous privilege. Possibly zealots of the "use powershell" heresy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because gold may not be a number on your first pass!

Comment: I thought the same at first. But most values do not cause the error. For example, undefined is OK, alpha value is OK. About the only things that fail are math operators other than `+` and `-`.

Comment: I'd rather suspect, %gold% is not defined on the first pass. Check contents after reading from file with `echo %gold%`

Comment: Exactly what my problem was ^

Answer (score 3):

Not really enough information.

I'd check the contents of `gold.dat`.

If the file does not exist, it will give you a different response.

If it is empty ( a zero-byte file) or contains simply a space newl-line or a new-line alone, the code will work happily.

If the file contains `,` and a newline, you'll get the error you report.

Comment: +1, Most values don't cause the error. Other values that do cause the error are operators like `/`, `*`, `&`, `^`, `|`, `<<`, `>>`, `=`

Comment: When you exit the game there is always a number in there. But when it starts it goes to wherever you were and when you work it screws up

Comment: Add an `@echo on` statement just before each `set /a` and look to see exactly what's happening. You should put a `PAUSE` before each `cls` of course - or a `pause&echo off` which would turn `echo` back off when you respond `ENTER`

Comment: I've got it now. It was because I was setting gold before I had set it from the gold.dat file.

Answer (score 3):

you should post the content of `"%CD%\Data Files\gold.dat"`, and, btw. you should remove the part `%CD%\` from the path, it is not neccesarry.

Comment: This answer is probably better as a comment. The `%CD%\` part is totally unnecessary, but it is a valid construct that one could argue "makes sense". The result is the same with or without it.